# 2021 Metrics missing?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New metrics had been posted annually until 2020. I don't see 2021 update on http://wiki.ros.org/Metrics nor on discourse.ros.org. Am I missing it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394076/2021-metrics-missing?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2022-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We haven't released a metrics report for 2021. I got bogged down trying to automate report generation and with the pivot from ROSCon to ROS World. Hopefully, I will have some time to create the report in a few weeks. Is there a specific metric you are looking for?

---

Originally posted by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) with karma: 209 on 2022-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2022-01-25**:
@kscottz Thanks, the annual report is generally helpful (as an industry professional who chooses platform for product for the next few years). That said, this time what I wanted to see was the user demographic per ROS distro, which I now can see in https://metrics.ros.org/packages_rosdistro.html

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2022-02-02**:
It's been announced!
https://discourse.ros.org/t/2021-ros-metrics-report/24130

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably you are looking for this?

https://metrics.ros.org/packages_rosdistro.html

It seems that report is a publication from various metrics available on https://metrics.ros.org/

---

Originally posted by [AravindaDP](https://answers.ros.org/users/27826/aravindadp/) with karma: 36 on 2022-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2022-01-12**:
Thx. That "packages_rosdistro.html" portion is one of the things I was looking for but could not find. But now I find the link at the top bar...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two separate sources for metrics. One is the metrics.ros.org site that I maintain. The second is a curated report that Open Robotics has been putting together, primarily @tfoote and @kscottz.

The first is updated monthly. The latter has not been published for 2021.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2022-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2